# React build - Container 'Build' exceeded memory limit error while building in docker

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker

I'm getting `Container 'Build' exceeded memory limit.` error when I'm trying to build my `react` application inside a docker. This build is working fine on my local machine.
Below is my docker image.

```
docker run -v `pwd`:/mycode -it --memory=8g --memory-swap=8g --memory-swappiness=0 node:14.15.1 /bin/sh
```

I tried increasing heap memory with `export NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8192` but no success.
One observation is, with the increasing size of my application its asking for more and more heap memory. Initially 2Gb heap memory was sufficient, then I increased it to 4Gb, and then 8Gb, but now even 8Gb is not sufficient.
Can somebody give me any pointer about how to check which process is asking for such a huge heap memory, any any possible solution to reduce this requirement?

Below is my `package.json` file.

```
{
  "name": "sample-application",
  "version": "0.7.13",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-amplify/analytics": "^2.0.0",
    "@aws-amplify/api": "^2.0.0",
    "@aws-amplify/auth": "^2.0.0",
    "@aws-amplify/core": "^2.0.0",
    "@aws-amplify/interactions": "^2.0.0",
    "@aws-amplify/storage": "^2.0.0",
    "@aws-amplify/ui": "^2.0.0",
    "@cubejs-client/core": "0.26.45",
    "@cubejs-client/react": "0.26.46",
    "@date-io/core": "^1.3.6",
    "@date-io/date-fns": "2.6.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.27",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.12.1",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.9",
    "@hapi/joi": "^17.1.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "4.11.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "4.9.1",
    "@material-ui/lab": "4.0.0-alpha.57",
    "@material-ui/pickers": "4.0.0-alpha.8",
    "@material-ui/styles": "4.10.0",
    "@rjsf/core": "2.2.2",
    "@rjsf/material-ui": "2.2.2",
    "@sibevin/random-token": "^1.0.2",
    "@slcloud/constants": "0.1.0",
    "@slcloud/locale": "0.1.0",
    "@slcloud/material-table": "1.69.9",
    "@slcloud/models": "0.1.0",
    "@slcloud/react-advanced-datetimerange-picker": "1.0.18",
    "@slcloud/shared": "0.1.0",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.157",
    "@types/react-dropzone": "^5.1.0",
    "amazon-cognito-identity-js": "4.3.3",
    "antd": "4.14.0",
    "aws-amplify": "3.0.23",
    "aws-amplify-react": "4.1.23",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.639.0",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "clsx": "^1.1.0",
    "countries-list": "^2.5.4",
    "date-fns": "2.15.0",
    "devextreme": "20.2",
    "devextreme-react": "20.2",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "google-map-react": "^1.1.7",
    "highcharts": "^8.0.4",
    "highcharts-react-official": "^3.0.0",
    "html2canvas": "^1.0.0-rc.7",
    "json-schema": "^0.2.5",
    "jspdf": "^2.2.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.19",
    "material-ui-color": "^1.0.0",
    "moment": "2.25.3",
    "moment-timezone": "0.5.31",
    "notistack": "0.9.9",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-app-rewire-babel-loader": "^0.1.1",
    "react-app-rewired": "^2.1.6",
    "react-color": "^2.19.3",
    "react-compound-slider": "^3.3.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-dropzone": "11.0.1",
    "react-ga": "^3.3.0",
    "react-grid-layout": "1.2.2",
    "react-hook-form": "5.0.3",
    "react-infinite-scroll-component": "5.0.4",
    "react-intl": "3.12.0",
    "react-jsonschema-form": "1.8.1",
    "react-redux": "7.1.3",
    "react-resizable": "1.11.1",
    "react-router": "5.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "react-tap-event-plugin": "^3.0.3",
    "react-visibility-sensor": "5.1.1",
    "react-zendesk": "^0.1.11",
    "recharts": "^2.0.0-beta.1",
    "redux": "4.0.5",
    "redux-saga": "1.1.3",
    "redux-saga-effects": "1.1.0",
    "redux-thunk": "2.3.0",
    "reselect": "^4.0.0",
    "survey-react": "^1.8.21",
    "typeface-poppins": "0.0.72",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "env-cmd -f ../shared/environments/.env react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test",
    "test-ci": "react-app-rewired test -- --watchAll=false",
    "eject": "react-app-rewired eject",
    "lint": "eslint --debug --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx ./src/",
    "lint-fix": "eslint --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx  --fix ./src/",
    "start:testv2": "env-cmd -f ../shared/environments/.env.testv2 react-app-rewired start",
    "start:cloudv2": "env-cmd -f ../shared/environments/.env.cloudv2 react-app-rewired start",
    "start:testperf": "env-cmd -f ../shared/environments/.env.testperf react-app-rewired start",
    "build:testv2": "env-cmd -f ../shared/environments/.env.testv2 react-app-rewired build",
    "build:cloudv2": "env-cmd -f ../shared/environments/.env.cloudv2 react-app-rewired build",
    "build:cloudappv2": "env-cmd -f ../shared/environments/.env.cloudappv2 react-app-rewired build",
    "build:testperf": "env-cmd -f ../shared/environments/.env.testperf react-app-rewired build",
    "test:coverage": "set CI=true && react-app-rewired test --coverage",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 9009 -s public",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook -s public",
    "analyze": "source-map-explorer 'build/static/js/*.js'"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.8.3",
    "@loadable/component": "^5.14.1",
    "@rest-hooks/test": "^1.0.14",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^5.3.17",
    "@storybook/addon-info": "^5.3.17",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^5.3.17",
    "@storybook/addon-viewport": "^5.3.17",
    "@storybook/addons": "^5.3.17",
    "@storybook/preset-create-react-app": "^2.0.0",
    "@storybook/react": "^5.3.17",
    "@svgr/parcel-plugin-svgr": "^5.3.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.1.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "@types/aws-sdk": "^2.7.0",
    "@types/enzyme": "3.10.4",
    "@types/enzyme-adapter-react-16": "1.0.5",
    "@types/google-map-react": "^1.1.5",
    "@types/hapi__joi": "^16.0.12",
    "@types/jest": "^25.2.1",
    "@types/loadable__component": "^5.13.3",
    "@types/material-ui": "^0.21.8",
    "@types/node": "12.12.26",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.19",
    "@types/react-color": "^3.0.4",
    "@types/react-dom": "16.9.5",
    "@types/react-grid-layout": "^1.1.1",
    "@types/react-jsonschema-form": "^1.7.4",
    "@types/react-redux": "7.1.7",
    "@types/react-router": "^5.1.4",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "5.1.3",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^16.9.2",
    "@types/redux": "^3.6.0",
    "@types/redux-mock-store": "^1.0.2",
    "@types/redux-thunk": "^2.1.0",
    "@types/sinon": "^7.5.2",
    "@types/storybook-react-router": "^1.0.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "2.18.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "2.18.0",
    "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.2",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.4.4",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "6.3.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "6.10.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "3.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.18.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "2.3.0",
    "fetch-mock": "^9.0.0-beta.2",
    "husky": "^4.2.3",
    "jest": "^25.1.0",
    "jest-fetch-mock": "^3.0.1",
    "prettier": "1.19.1",
    "react-docgen-typescript-loader": "^3.7.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.12.0",
    "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.4",
    "sinon": "^9.0.0",
    "source-map-explorer": "^2.5.2",
    "storybook": "^5.3.17",
    "storybook-addon-material-ui": "^0.9.0-alpha.21",
    "storybook-addon-responsive-views": "^2.3.0",
    "storybook-react-router": "^1.0.8",
    "ts-jest": "^25.2.1",
    "ts-loader": "^6.2.1",
    "typescript": "3.9.6"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "npm run lint-fix"
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,json,css,scss,md}": [
      "prettier — single-quote — write",
      "git add"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I faced similar problem a while ago - have you tried increasing also the maximum memory that docker can use? Not in package.json, but in your docker configuration (in my case docker was using 2gb unless I've changed it in the main config)

Comment: Thanks for response. Yes I tried increasing docker memory to 8Gb. But still no success. 8Gb for building react looks decent enough. So looks like something is going wrong within a code. Just wanted to know if there's some way to track what's going wrong

Comment: The problem is Storybook. I have the same issue. Even with 8GB in Docker, the build still fails with exit code 137: run out of memory. I've made sure it's not trying to look in node_modules files and even disabled reactDocgen but no luck